Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int^1_0\left(1+x^{9}+x^{21}+x^{36}+\cdots \right)\ \mathrm dx$

Evaluation  of $\left(\displaystyle \frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{45}+\frac{1}{63}+\cdots\right) $

What I try: I am trying to solve it using Integration,
So we have
$\displaystyle =\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(x^8+x^{17}+x^{29}+x^{44}+x^{62}+\cdots \bigg)\ \mathrm dx$
$\displaystyle =\int^1_0x^{8}\bigg(1+x^9+x^{21}+x^{36}+\cdots \bigg)\ \mathrm dx$
The above series is not in the infinite geometric series.
I did not understand how I could solve it after that.
Please have a look at this; thanks.

What is the sequence in the denominators? Three times triangular numbers, or what?

if $a_{n}=3,6,10,15,21\dots $ Then it seems that $a_{n+1}-a_n $ is an arithmetic progression sequence with difference 1.
And OP's sequence is just $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3\cdot a_{n}} $

try $\int_0^1\bigl(\int_0^t(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)dx\bigr) dt $

Without using calculus, the given infinite series can be easily evaluated as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}\frac19+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{45}+\frac{1}{63}+\cdots=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3T_{n+1}}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{3(n+1)(n+2)}\\&=\frac23\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\\&=\frac23\cdot\frac12\qquad\text{(telescoping series)}\\\color{red}{\frac19+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{45}+\frac{1}{63}+\cdots}&\color{red}{=\frac13}\end{aligned}$$

If you use calculus, the integrand $(1+x^9+x^{21}+x^{36}+\cdots)$ seems to be expressed in terms of Jacobi's theta functions, i.e., $\vartheta_2(0,q)=2q^{1/4}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n(n+1)}$.
The $n$th term of the sequence $0,\ 9,\ 21,\ 36,\ldots$ is $(3T_{n+1}-9)$, where $T_n=\binom{n+1}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is $n$th triangular number (OEIS: A000217).
$$1+x^9+x^{21}+x^{36}+\cdots=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{3T_{n+1}-9}=\frac{1}{x^9}\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{3n(n+1)/2}=\dfrac{(x^{3/2})^{3/4}\vartheta_2(0,x^{3/2})}{2x^{21/2}}-\dfrac{1+x^3}{x^9}\tag{1}$$
$$x^8(1+x^9+x^{21}+x^{36}+\cdots)=\dfrac{(x^{3/2})^{3/4}\vartheta_2(0,x^{3/2})}{2x^{5/2}}-\dfrac{1+x^3}{x}=\dfrac{\vartheta_2(0,x^{3/2})-2x^{3/8}}{2x^{11/8}}-x^2\tag{2}$$
Clearly, evaluating the integral of the expression involving $\vartheta_2(0,x^{3/2})$ is complex, and it leads to the series we are trying to evaluate.
The integral is given by,
$$\int_0^1x^8(1+x^9+x^{21}+x^{36}+\cdots)\ \mathrm dx=\int_0^1\dfrac{\vartheta_2(0,x^{3/2})-2x^{3/8}}{2x^{11/8}}\ \mathrm dx-\frac13\tag{3}$$
As we have already evaluated the series as $1/3$, we can conclude that the integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ must converge, and
$$\boxed{\int_0^1\dfrac{\vartheta_2(0,x^{3/2})-2x^{3/8}}{2x^{11/8}}\ \mathrm dx=\frac23}$$
I hope you find it interesting!

The integral as a side result is interesting, nice answer

I present a separate method not involving calculus.
We try to find a pattern in the sequence $a_n$ with initial terms $9, 18, 30, 45\dots$ and so on. Out of the many patterns one can interpolate, one which is most obvious is that the differences of consecutive terms is in arithmetic progression. More specifically, $a_{n+1}-a_n = 3n+6$. Since the first order of difference of $a_n$ is linear, the general term $a_n$ must be a quadratic.
Thus $a_n = an^2+bn+c$. Then $a+b+c=9$, $4a+2b+c=18$ and $9a+3b+c=30$. Solving we have $a=\frac32$, $b=\frac92$ and $c=3$. Thus we are to figure out $$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac2{3x^2+9x+6} = \frac23\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac1{x+1} -\frac1{x+2}\right)$$ which telescopes.

Beautiful, thanks!

@MJD thank you for the kind words
